# Google API: Customer is not an AdSense Host

Tags: google-api, adsense-api

### What I'm trying to do?

List and create AdSense ad units using Google API.

### What have I tried?

1. Went to [adunits.list on Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/adsensehost/v4.1/adsensehost.accounts.adunits.list).
2. Inserted in my accountId and adClientId (pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX, ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
3. Clicked 'Execute'.
4. I received error 403 "Customer is not an AdSense Host".
5. Looked for online answers without much success, so here I am on StackOverflow.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an AdSense publisher with regular AdSense account, you can't use AdSense for Host API.

AdSense Host API is for host partner websites (Blogger, WebAnswers, DocStoc, etc.) and it enables site-owners to share revenue with their users.

https://developers.google.com/adsense/host/featuresbenefits
https://developers.google.com/adsense/host/become-a-host#eligibility

You can use AdSense Management API `adsense.accounts.adunits.list` to retreive the list of your units. (But, you can't create new units with Management API.)

https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/accounts/adunits/list

Comment: Thanks! Do I have to be Host API in order to use `adsense.accounts.adunits.list`?

Comment: No, you don't need to be Host Partner. For AdSense Management API you just need AdSense account, and to register your application in APIs Console. https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/getting_started

Comment: This is really unfortunate. So regular users have no way to automate creation of ads for their site.